# Allowing iPhone installation without iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I would like to deploy iOS Apps, built for my in house staff, on their devices by clicking a link (like http://www.srx.com.sg/appstore). Looking at deployment for over 300 devices. Is it possible to do so like the example link i provided without submitting the App to iTune Store? If so, how?

Comment: you can make your application enterprise application and distribute it.

Comment: any limit to number of devices for deployment? i don't see that in the apple website.

Comment: No limit... for more information you can go through link http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/deployment.html?lang=en-us#app43ad871e